# LibAV FFMPEG How to get devices list?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav

I looked up to documantation and found a very convenient `AVInputFormat`'s funciton `get_device_list` . But the problem is I can't use it.

Here's my short code snippet

```
#include <QDebug>

extern "C"
{
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    avdevice_register_all();

    AVFormatContext *formatContext = avformat_alloc_context();

    AVInputFormat *inputFormat = av_find_input_format("dshow");

    AVDeviceInfoList devices;
    inputFormat->get_device_list(formatContext, &devices);

    qDebug() << devices.nb_devices;

    avformat_free_context(formatContext);

    return 0;
}
```

And that code **CRASHES** when I'm trying to print `devices`. How do I use that function properly? The official domentation has no examples using that function.

Comment: I'm fairly certain `devices` needs to point to a valid `AVDeviceInfoList` when you pass it to `get_device_list` .

Comment: Fixed my question. The problem still remains

Comment: You may have undefined behaviour elsewhere.  Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: made it as minimal as I could

Comment: Does `av_find_input_format("dshow")` return a valid pointer?

Comment: Well, it's not nullptr so I guess yes, the pointer is valid